# How to update a AnimationGroup without creating a new AnimationGroup every time?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to run a AnimationGroup with different changing animations.
But the problem is that the function clear()

```
    self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)
def anim(self):
    if X == True:
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation_1)
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation_2)
    elif X == False:
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation_3)
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation_4)
    self.group.start()
    self.group.clear()
```

displays an error

> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QVariantAnimation has been deleted

I can’t constantly create a new group.

```
def anim(self):
    self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)
    if X == True:
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation_1)
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation_2)
    elif X == False:
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation_3)
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation_4)
    self.group.start()
    self.group.clear()
```

I tried to use `removeAnimation`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Rad(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, group, pos, parent=None):
        super(Rad,  self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(50, 50)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText('but-{}'.format(pos))
        self.group = group
        self.pos = pos
        lay.addWidget(self.radio)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)
        self.radio.toggled.connect(self.fun)
        self.animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation() 
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)  
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.value)
        self.animation.setStartValue(100)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        self.can = False
    def value(self, val):
        self.move(self.pos, val)
    def fun(self):
        self.animation.setStartValue(
            100
            if not self.can 
            else 0
        )
        self.animation.setEndValue(
            0
            if not self.can 
            else 100
        )
        if self.group.animationAt(1) == None :
            print("Bad")
        else :
            print("Good")
            self.group.removeAnimation(self.group.animationAt(0))
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation)
        self.group.start()
        self.can = not self.can

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)
        self.buts = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self, exclusive=True)
        wid_1 = Rad(self.group,   200, self)
        wid_2 = Rad(self.group,  100, self)
        wid_3 = Rad(self.group,  0, self)
        self.buts.addButton(wid_1.radio, 0)
        self.buts.addButton(wid_2.radio,1)
        self.buts.addButton(wid_3.radio, 2)
        wid_1.setStyleSheet('background:brown;')
        wid_2.setStyleSheet('background:yellow;')
        wid_3.setStyleSheet('background:green;')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And now the animation has become sharp

[image]

And in the console output

> QAnimationGroup::animationAt: index is out of bounds

Comment: In the 2 initial codes they are incomplete that do not help to understand the problem, the third code is more complete but still confusing. What is your practical objective? You have 3 radio buttons. What should happen if any QRadioButton is pressed? From what I understand you want the pressed QRadioButton to move its position and the previously moved QRadioButton to return to its initial position, am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can deduce is that you want the pressed item to move down and if any item was in the low position then it must return to its position. If so then my answer should work.

You should not use the clear method since that removes and deletes the animation, instead use `takeAnimation(0)` until there are no animations, and just add the new animations, but that logic should not be inside "Rad" but in the Test class:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Rad(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(Rad, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(50, 50)
        self.radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText(text)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.radio)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)

        self.animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.on_value_changed)
        self.animation.setStartValue(100)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QVariant")
    def on_value_changed(self, val):
        pos = self.pos()
        pos.setY(val)
        self.move(pos)

    def swap_values(self):
        self.animation.blockSignals(True)
        start_value = self.animation.startValue()
        end_value = self.animation.endValue()
        self.animation.setStartValue(end_value)
        self.animation.setEndValue(start_value)
        self.animation.blockSignals(False)


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.buts = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self, exclusive=True)
        wid_1 = Rad("but-200", self)
        wid_1.setStyleSheet("background:brown;")
        wid_1.move(200, 0)

        wid_2 = Rad("but-100", self)
        wid_2.setStyleSheet("background:yellow;")
        wid_2.move(100, 0)

        wid_3 = Rad("but-0", self)
        wid_3.setStyleSheet("background:green;")
        wid_3.move(0, 0)

        self.buts.addButton(wid_1.radio, 0)
        self.buts.addButton(wid_2.radio, 1)
        self.buts.addButton(wid_3.radio, 2)

        self.buts.buttonToggled.connect(self.on_button_toggled)

        self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)

        self.last_widget = None

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton, bool)
    def on_button_toggled(self, button, state):
        if state:
            wid = button.parent()
            if self.group.animationCount() > 0:
                self.group.takeAnimation(0)
            if isinstance(self.last_widget, Rad):
                self.last_widget.swap_values()
                self.group.addAnimation(self.last_widget.animation)
            wid.swap_values()
            self.group.addAnimation(wid.animation)
            self.group.start()
            self.last_widget = wid


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```